# Tracking which list element has been clicked on and transferring this data into PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a series of list items that when clicked will submit a form with hidden input values. The problem is that I cannot seem to work out how to pull out the list index number from HTML and transfer this into the PHP logic check to display the name of the input field clicked to the right of the list.

```
<?php
    $students = ['bob','paul'];     
?>

<section id="tablet_container">

    <div class="upload-tableview-wrapper">

        <ul>
            <form id="select_student" name="select_student" method='POST' action="<?php echo ($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>">
                <li><input type="hidden" name="student_firstname[]" value="<?php echo $students[0]; ?>">
                    <?php echo $students[0];?>
                </li>
                <li><input type="hidden" name="student_firstname[]" value="<?php echo $students[1]; ?>">
                    <?php echo $students[1];?>
                    <li>
            </form>
        </ul>

        </div>

<?php
    if (isset($_POST['student_firstname'])) {      
?>
    <div id="manual_student_container">
        <label id="label_student_first_name"> First Name:</label>
        <input type="text" readonly name="student_first_name" id="student_first_name" value="<?php echo $_POST['student_firstname'][1]; ?>">
    </div>
    </section>
<?php
    }     
?>
```

Javascript -jquery

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    //colour selection rd and submit the form
    $('li').click(function () {
        $('li').css({ "background-color": "#F7F7F7" });
        $(this).css({ "background-color": "red" });

        var selectedStudent = $(this).text();

        // Remove saved data from sessionStorage
        sessionStorage.removeItem('selectedStudent');
        //store the new value
        sessionStorage.setItem('selectedStudent', selectedStudent);

        $('#select_student').submit();
    });
});
```

CSS

```
.upload-tableview-wrapper {
    position:absolute;
    height: 270px;
    width: 200px;
    top:60px;
    left:80px;
    box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0px 1px 0px  rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
    overflow: scroll;
    background-color: black;
}

ul {
    list-style-type:none;
    font-family:"Helvetica";
    font-size:16px;
    padding:0;
}

ul li {
    background-color:#F7F7F7;
    padding:14px 10px;
    border-left:1px solid #B2B4B8;
    border-right:1px solid #B2B4B8;
    border-bottom:1px solid #CBCBCB;
    border-top:1px solid #FDFDFD;
    color:#385487;
}

ul li:hover {
    color:white;
    background-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Submit()` is for forms and will automatically submit to whatever form's action is set to in HTML.

Like `<form action="/action_page.php" method="post">`

Are you sending the input values to any php script/page?

---

Edit: 
Well, first of all make sure text() actually gets the value you want. I'd suggest using val() on the inputs just to be safe.

`var selectedStudent=$(this).children('input').val();`

Comment: Don't you see `action = "<?php echo ($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>"` in the HTML?

Comment: My bad, didn't see the scrolling. I am editing my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can fill a hidden input with the selected value and submit the form

```
<input type="hidden" name="selected_student" id="selected_student" value="" />

<script>
$('li').click(function() 
{
    $('li').css({"background-color": "#F7F7F7"});
    $(this).css({"background-color": "red" });

    var  selectedStudent=$(this).text();

    $('#selected_student').val(selectedStudent);
    $('#select_student').submit();
}  
</script>
```

You can then access the value in PHP with `$_POST['selected_student']`

Comment: I already have done this - my question is about how to track which li element was clicked prior to the form submission so the correct name is echoed to the text input tag to the right of the list